# How can a Bayesian analysis say A < B, when both have only 0s?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, ab-test

I've used python to analyse data from AB tests using Bayesian analysis, and for all tests I assume no prior knowledge and so set `alpha = beta = 1`.

However I'm finding some odd results at low data volumes, which I thought was my code, but I'm also seeing using an [online Bayesian calculator](http://developers.lyst.com/bayesian-calculator/). This leads me to believe I don't understand the maths properly :).

If we take an AB test with the following parameters:

```
A trials: 100
A successes: 0

B trials: 10
B successes: 0
```

There is a 90% chance that B is better according to the analysis, however I don't understand how this can be the case with no successes recorded yet? Otherwise, the true success rate could be 0.00001% and this analysis should yield a low level of significance...

So is this the case? Assuming it is, how can I adjust parameters to ensure that there is no assumption on the success rate (or at least that I can control this assumption).

Comment: If your code is not [returning a Beta$(k+1,n-k+1)$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) for $k$ successes in $n$ trials, then what is it doing?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So if I want to avoid this, I can specify a weakly informed prior based on what I believe is a more likely  outcome. I think I was just surprised given what I had read about a uniform prior (and my lack of rigorous understanding of the maths). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Bayesian expert, but I think this is simpler than it appears.  Your data seem to be [binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), and the [uninformative prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors) for a binomial has an expected value of $.5$—albeit with equal likelihood for all probabilities.  The [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) is [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), and you get the [uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) with a beta if $\alpha = \beta = 1$, which I believe is what you are referring to.  The posterior in a Bayesian analysis can be thought of simply as a weighted average of your prior and your data.  So as you observe $0$s, your posterior will slide from $.5$ towards $0$.  More $0$s will make it slide further.  Thus, with more observations in `A`, the posterior will be dominated by the data, whereas with few observations in `B`, the posterior is dominated by the prior, and the analyst believes $Pr(Y=1|A)<Pr(Y=1|B)$.

To think about this by analogy using frequentist techniques, consider the task of forming a confidence interval for $p$ from binomial data with all $0$s.  A simple approach to determining the upper limit of a 95% CI (the lower limit is obviously $0$) is to use the [rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28statistics%29); *viz*.: $3/N$.  For your data, the frequentist 95% CIs are, $[0,\ .03]$ for `A`, and $[0,\ .3]$ for `B`.